# UWSGI --cheap and --idle modes - expected behaviour

Tags: memory, uwsgi

I'm running django on uwsgi using the following command

```
uwsgi --master --cheap --idle 60 --http-socket :8084 --wsgi-file /var/django/mysite/django.wsgi
```

Typically my processes sit at around 10mb each, but I have seen them sitting at around half a MB. My question is, does uwsgi drop the processes down to an even cheaper mode when the server is running out of memory? If anyone can explain exactly how --cheap and --idle work, that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Doc):

> **cheap**
>     postpone workers startup until the first request
>
> **cheaper**
>     an advanced cheap mode, this will only spawn `<n>` workers on startup and will use various (pluggable) algorithms to implement adaptive process spawining.
>
> **idle**
>     destroy workers (the server will go in cheap mode) after `<secs>` of inactivity

So basically those options reduce memory usage by only running workers when they are actually needed. The downside is slightly higher latency because workers have to be started when the request comes in.

Comment: Thanks, I had read that in the docs but I'm mainly curious as to how my processes dropped to ~500kb. Any idea?

Comment: @Greg I would presume that there are currently no workers running then. Are all the processes like that? Is the site currently serving requests?

Comment: Yes and yes - what I observed was all the processes were at ~500kb, but when I browsed to the site, the process for that site jumped up to the usual level of memory usage and served the request.